# Java - Change behavior Tab key

Tags: java, tabs, focus

i have simple gui app and, when I press Tab key, it move focus like this:

[image: img]

but i wanna move like this:

[image: img]

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;   

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    // NetBeans generate Form code

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a custom FocusTraversalPolicy. see here for an example -> [Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal)

Comment: I try edit code from this side, but it doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: what does your FocusTraversalPolicy class look like? Are there any errors? can you post your full code?